# Aws RedShift sampling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

For a data quality check I need to collect data in a specific interval.
Some tables are huge in size.

Is there any hack to do this without affecting the performance?

Like select 100 rows randomly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How random do you need?  The classic way to do this is with "WHERE RANDOM() < .001".  If you need it to give you a repeatable "random" set then you can add a seed.  The issue is that your tables are huge and this means reading (scanning) every row from disk just to throw most of them away and since table scan can take a significant time this isn't what you want to do.

So you may want to take advantage of Redshift "limited table scan" capabilities as part of your "random" sampling.  (The fastest data to read from disk is the data you don't read from disk.)  The issue here is that this solution will depend on your table sort keys and ordering which will push the solution into even "more pseudo" random territory (less of a true random sampling).  In many cases this isn't a big deal but if the statistics really matter then this may not work for you.

This is done by sampling "blocks", not rows, based on the sort key(s).  This sampling of blocks can be done randomly and each block of data will represent about 250K rows (based on sort key data type, compression etc. and COULD range anywhere from <100K rows to 2M rows).  Doing this process will take a little inspection of STV_BLOCKLIST.  The storage quanta for Redshift is the 1MB block and each and every block's metadata in the system can be referenced in STV_BLOCKLIST.  This system table contains min and max values for each block.  First find all the blocks for the sort key for the table in question.  Next pick a random sample of these blocks (and if you are still dealing with a lot of data make sure that this sampling picks an even number from across all the slices to avoid execution skew).

Now the trick is to translate these min a max metadata values into a WHERE clause the performs the desired sampling.  These min and max values are BIGINTs and are hashed from the data in the sort key column.  This hash is data type dependent.  If the data type is BIGINT then the has is quite simple - if the data type is timestamp then it is a bit more complex.  But the ordering will be preserved across the hashing function for the data type involved.  Reverse engineering this hash isn't hard - just perform a few experiments - but I can help if you tell me the type involved as I've done this for just about every data type at this point.

You can even do a random sampling rows on top of this random sampling of blocks.  Or if you want you can just pick some narrow ranges of the sort key value and then randomly sample row and avoid all this reverse engineering business.  The idea is to use Redshift "reduced scan" capability to greatly reduce the amount of data read from disk.  To do this you need to be metadata aware in your choice of sampling windows which often means a sort key where clause.  This is all about understanding how the database engine works and using its capabilities to your advantage.

I understand that this answer is based on some unstated information so please reach out in a comment if something isn't clear.